# Do I need to hash before using openssl_sign?

Tags: php, hash, sign, digest, php-openssl

The 4th argument of the  [***openssl_sign***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php) function is the signing digest algorithm.

So, does that mean that the ***openssl_sign*** function already does the hashing before signing it?

Or should I still hash my data before passing to ***openssl_sign***?